# How to concatenate javascript one varaibles into another

Tags: javascript

i have two arrays,based on the language selection have to change labels values

```
var GlobalArray = { 
    lang:'english'
}


var arrayValues = {

    data: {
         english:
        {
          fname: 'FirstName',

          },
           spanish:
        {
          fname: '1221',

          }
    }
}
```

when lang got english ,english array need to show. when spanish value got in lang, spanish fname and lname should show .

try to concatenate both array value and global array in javascript,it showing issues.like below

```
arrayValues.data.""+GlobalArray.lang+"".fname
```

Comment: *i have two arrays*....you don't have any array!!!

Comment: `arrayValues.data[GlobalArray.lang].fname` is this what you want?

Comment: "it showing issues.like below"--What is the issue it is showing?

Comment: You don't even have ONE array

Comment: first, understand the difference between json object and array. array functions is not gonna work on object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arrayValues.data[GlobalArray.lang].fname` use this to get values in array value  for e.g.`arrayValues.data["english"].fname`

`arrayValues.data.""+GlobalArray.lang+"".fname` issue might be `Unexpected string`

Answer (score 1):

Since your value is contained in a variable (`GlobalArray.lang` property), you have to use [bracket access notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access the right sub-object in `arrayValues.data`:

```
const fname = arrayValues.data[GlobalArray.lang].fname
```

To make it work with concatenation, you would have to evaluate the resulting expression with [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), which I do not recommend:

```
const fname = eval('arrayValues.data.' + GlobalArray.lang + '.fname')
```

Here is an example:

```js
const GlobalArray = { 
  lang: 'english'
}

const arrayValues = {
  data: {
   english: { fname: 'FirstName' },
   spanish: { fname: '1221'  }
  }
}

function langChanged(value) {
  GlobalArray.lang = value;
  console.log(arrayValues.data[GlobalArray.lang].fname);
  console.log(eval('arrayValues.data.' + GlobalArray.lang + '.fname'));
}

langChanged('english');
```

```html
Select a language:
<select onchange="langChanged(event.target.value)">
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="spanish">Spanish</option>
</select>
```